# Mysql Insert with subquery

Tags: mysql, insert, in-clause

I'm trying to insert several records like this :

```
SET @user_id = (select `id` from users where `email` IN( 'carlos+01@comp.com', 'carlos+223344@comp.com' ) );

SET @badge_id = (select `id` from badges where `slug` = 'elearning_nutrition');

INSERT INTO `instructor_badges` (`id`, `user_id`, `badge_id`, `is_active`, `is_manual`, `created`)
VALUES (UUID(), @user_id, @badge_id, '1', '0', NOW());
```

but im getting this error:

> [ERROR in query 1] Subquery returns more than 1 row

In this case I would have to insert 2 records. How could I perform this query?

Comment: You want to insert two records? Or you just want to defeat the "Subquery returns more than 1 row" error? In the second case, just put "LIMIT 1" onto your subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this. This will cartesian join users to badges, though. So if you select two users and two badges you will get four rows to insert. But I think that's what you are saying you want to achieve.

```
INSERT INTO instructor_badges (id, user_id, badge_id, is_active, is_manual, created)
SELECT UUID(), users.id, badges.id, '1', '0', NOW()
FROM users 
JOIN badge
WHERE users.email IN( 'carlos+01@comp.com', 'carlos+223344@comp.com' )
&& badges.slug = 'elearning_nutrition'
```

Comment: Thank you in my case the badge is only one .
What do you think if I do something like this which I see is working as well.
        
        SET @badge_id = (select `id` from badges where `slug` = 'elearning_nutrition');
INSERT INTO `instructor_badges` (`user_id`, `id`,  `badge_id`, `is_active`, `is_manual`, `created`)
select `id` , UUID(), @badge_id , '1', '0', NOW() from users where `email` IN( 'fernando+01@comp.com', 'carlos+223344@comp.com' )

Comment: Yes, that looks lovely to me.

Comment: Note that you can also just use your subquery directly if you would like to avoid the `@badge_id` variable.

Answer (score 0):

OK I solved in this way , is there another better way because I had to write user_id in first position :

```
 SET @badge_id = (select `id` from badges where `slug` = 'elearning_nutrition');

INSERT INTO `instructor_badges` (`user_id`, `id`,  `badge_id`, `is_active`, `is_manual`, `created`)
select `id` , UUID(), @badge_id , '1', '0', NOW() from users where `email`   IN( 'german+01@zumba.com', 'german+223344@zumba.com' )
```

Comment: Why did you have to write it in first position?

Comment: In the future, you can just edit my Answer rather than providing your own so that we get more consensus on the right answer. Thanks.